# std::bind not working

Tags: c++, c++11, bind

I can't get `std::bind` to work the same way `boost::bind` works.  Either I'm not using it correctly, or my compiler (GCC 4.4.5) doesn't implement it correctly yet.

I have two functions:

```
void f(int x, int y)
{
    cout << x << " | " << y << endl;
}

template <class UnaryFunction>
void g(UnaryFunction func)
{
    func(100);
}
```

I use bind to call `f` as a unary function in g:

```
g(std::bind(f, 10, std::placeholders::_1));
```

This results in a compiler error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<void (*(int, std::_Placeholder<1>))(int, int)>) (int)’
```

... followed by a page or so of template compiler vomit.

If I use `boost::bind`, like:

```
g(boost::bind(f, 10, _1));
```

...it works fine.  Are the semantics of `std::bind` somehow different, or is this a compiler issue?

Comment: AFAIK std::bind and boost::bind are different in implementation and work differently, boost::bind has more flexibility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's just your version of compiler, gcc 4.5.1 ([via ideone.com](http://ideone.com/HfO00)) and 4.6.0 compile it correctly.